# How to stop filebeat stop forwarding the logs?

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Is it possible to  stop  forwarding the logs from filebeat forwarder server to logstash instead of using systemctl disable filebeat ?

Comment: Please clarify why you want to stop forwarding logs or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why would you want to run the filebeat service and not let it forward logs ? That state is quivalent to stopping the service.

Comment: I have maybe a very similar problem; I'dd like to get the logs only when the most important traffic isn't so present because I can't use another way than the same NIC under very heavy load during a certain period.